# How manage several transactions in one transactional method in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have next code

```
@Transactional
public void f1() {
    try {
        lock();
        //some logic
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        releaseLock();
    }


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void lock() {
     repository.doLock();
   }


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void releaseLock() {
         repository.doReleaseLock();
    }
```

I want to have next behavior: if something goes wrong in *some logic* lock will be released.
In the debug and in logs i see very strange behavior.
Code workflow never visit finally.

So, my question is: how correct this code to have 3 transactions which rollbacks altogether if one of them fails?

Comment: 1. You suppressed exception. 2. You messed-up with transaction conception - "have 3 transactions which rollbacks altogether if one of them fails" - it has no sense at all. Transaction is a set of operations/actions which rollback all together if something is wrong. Your "3 transactions" are not transactions, but 3 actions on one and only one transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you code should keep only (with throws statement):

```
 @Transactional
 public void f1() {    
    //some logic
 }
```